# deserialize json to array of entities

Tags: symfony, deserialization

I would like to deserialize a JSON to an object having an entity relation.

incoming JSON data

```
    {
          "name": "john",
          "books": [
            {
              "title": "My life"
            }
          ]
    }
```

The result of json deserialization like this

```
$object = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize($jsonData, 'Author', 'json');
```

is

```
 Author { #name: 'john' #books: array:1 [ 0 => array:1 [ "title" => "My life" ] ] }
```

I would like to deserialize to an object like this

```
Author { #name: 'john' #books: array:1 [ Book { "title" => "My life" } ] }
```

I understand why deserialization is not able to deserialize Book. With JMSSerialzerBundle, the Type annotation exists to resolve that case.

Is it possible to do it with the Symfony Serializer component or must i use the JMSSerializer for that ?

Thanks for your help ;)

My objects

```
class Author

    {
        private $name;

        private $books;

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $name
         */
        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getBooks()
        {
            return $this->books;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $books
         */
        public function setBooks(array $books)
        {
            $this->books = $books;
        }
    }

    class Book
    {
        private $title;

        private $author;

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getTitle()
        {
            return $this->title;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $title
         */
        public function setTitle($title)
        {
            $this->title = $title;
        }

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getAuthor()
        {
            return $this->author;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $author
         */
        public function setAuthor(Author $author)
        {
            $this->author = $author;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What especially do you want to do? Send some data to a rest API?

Comment: Just want to mention there's a doctrine dbal driver for rest so you don't need to care about almost anything

Comment: @Tobias i implement a web service "API like", but i don't use doctrine to persist data. I want to deserialize data to an object (with entity associations) with constraint violations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guilhem is right, the default Symfony `ObjectNormalizer` isn't able to normalize properties of non scalar types for now.

However, this feature is being added in Symfony 3.1: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/17660

In the meantime, you can copy/paste the `ObjectNormalizer` version provided in the PR linked above in your project.

You can also take a look at a similar implementation available in [API Platform](https://api-platform.com):

- https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/src/Bridge/Symfony/PropertyInfo/Metadata/Property/PropertyInfoPropertyMetadataFactory.php#L48-L51
- https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/src/JsonLd/Serializer/ItemNormalizer.php#L155-L178

Answer (score 1):

The symfony serializer can't denormalize complex properties.

I think that the only way to do that is to manage your object denormalization by yourself:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;

class Author implements DenormalizableInterface {
    public function denormalize(DenormalizerInterface $denormalizer, $data, $format = null, array $context = array()) {
        if (isset($data['name'])) {
            $this->setName($data['name']);
        }
        if (isset($data['books']) && is_array($data['books'])) {
            $books = array();
            foreach ($data['books'] as $book) {
                $books[] = $denormalizer->denormalize($book, Book::class, $format, $context);
            }
            $this->setBooks($books);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can also create a custom normalizer but this is more complicated (you can take a look at [this article](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/01/the-symfony2-serializer-component-create-a-normalizer-for-json-class-hinting/) which explains more or less how to do that).

I hope this will help you :-)

Comment: Thanks @Guilhem i'll try this